# How should I read image files uploaded by user and store the paths in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, file-upload, web-applications

I am using this right now to read a directory and then take each image and save them in a Array List:

```
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the directory path of the images (for eg c:\\test)");
    String imgPath=s.nextLine();
    ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<>();
    File f=new File(imgPath);
    File[] f2=f.listFiles();
    for(File f3:f2)
    {
        links.add(f3.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

How do I modify it so that I can do the same to image files that are being uploaded by user in a web application, and save as an ArrayList of String. Is it possible? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you expect those paths int ArrayList to look like? How do you plan to use them?

Comment: Look something like this: directoryPath\imgName.jpg.

And I am passing the ArrayList<String> to another method that converts the images to a video.

Comment: User (browser) doesn't send path to file, only file name and its bytes. If you would like to use `List<String>` then first you would need to store sent images on *your* machine/server because `path/imageName.jpg` describes *local* file system. Maybe consider using alternative solution which will accept `List<byte[]>` or `List<BufferedImage>` where you will pass image data (bytes) directly and convert it to video.

Comment: I plan on storing the uploaded images on the server.

Comment: @Pshemo I tried changing my method to accept List<BufferedImage[]>, but it isn't working as expected, it'd be great if you could help me with List<String>